# High camera position in Unity3D LWRP only shows gray materials

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, lwrp

I'm quite new in Unity lightweight render pipeline and in my current prototype I've noticed a behaviour which surprised me a bit since I've never seen it using the built-in or the high definition render pipeline.
I have a simple cube and I've assigned a yellow material to it. When I move the camera position to the top the cube material fades out to grey. Why does that happen?

*Camera Y position at around 20*
[image: y position at 20]

*Camera Y position at around 47*
[image: y position at 47]

Is that a lightweight behaviour or is there a opportunity to make the material appear in yellow like in the other pipelines? That only happens when controlling the camera in perspective mode btw.
Post processing is active in default scene but I've disabled it to secure it´s not a PP setting.

Would be cool if someone could drop a short message about that. I've searched on google but I wasn't able to find information about that behaviour.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and happened to stumble upon this question while doing some research myself. Since you posted your question about 2 months ago chances are you already have solved the issue or moved forward some other way but I thought I would just post an explanation as well as how to fix it if someone were to find this in the future wondering the same thing.

This is not really related to the LWRP itself as it's a feature of the example scene the LWRP gives you upon first creating the project. In that scene, a feature called "Fog" is enabled by default and that is what's causing the issue as your material is obstructed by the fog. Turning this off is quite easy although I usually create a new scene and start from there every time i make a new project using the LWRP since it's quicker than removing the pre-made stuff and changing this setting!

**However, to disable it you just need to go to:**

> **Window/Rendering/Lightning Settings**

**And scroll to the very bottom of the new menu where you will find a small box you can uncheck to make the effect disappear!**

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Yeah, I found it out by myself but forgot to update the question/add the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

That's look like a fog effect which affect the cube. Can you show me a snapshot where the distance (relativity far) between the cube and camera from any angle except from top ?

You might check your rendering settings or volume settings in scene which created by unity each time new scene created and you can check this article https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/Manual/PostProcessing-Fog.html to turn off fog manually.

If the problem still occurs can you share the project files?